# Draw only resized area of NSView

Tags: objective-c, performance, cocoa, optimization, nsview

I'm trying to draw an NSView efficiently, even when resizing. According to the docs for `-drawRect:`, I can use `-getRectsBeingDrawn:count:` to figure out what exactly needs to be redrawn and only redraw that. Furthermore, if I want to have live-resizing preserve content, I should return YES from `-preservesContentDuringLiveResize` and override `-setFrameSize:` and use `-getRectsExposedDuringLiveResize:count:` to determine what to mark as needing display. But while live-resizing the window, inside `-drawRect:` the `-getRectsBeingDrawn:count:` method still returns the entire bounds of the NSView rather than just the newly exposed part of the view. I confirm this using the NSView subclass below (auto-sized to always fill the window) and by dragging the window's bottom edge downward.

```c
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    const NSRect* rects;
    NSInteger count;
    [self getRectsBeingDrawn:&rects count:&count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSRect r = rects[i];
        [[[NSColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] drawSwatchInRect:r];
    }
}

- (BOOL) preservesContentDuringLiveResize {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL) isOpaque {
    return YES;
}

- (void) setFrameSize:(NSSize)newSize {
    [super setFrameSize:newSize];

    if ([self inLiveResize]) {
        NSRect rects[4];
        NSInteger count;
        [self getRectsExposedDuringLiveResize:rects count:&count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            NSRect r = rects[i];
            [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:r];
        }
    }
    else {
        [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    }
}
```